# The on Edit() trigger does not work for another account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a script that creates an on Edit() trigger for sheets
the owner of the script is account A

```
    function createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger(sheetId) {
                  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
                     .forSpreadsheet(sheetId)
                     .onEdit()
                     .create()
                  }

function myOnEdit() {
           
              const yourWebAppUrl = "https://xxx.ngrok.io/notifications";
              var options = {method: "post"};
              UrlFetchApp.fetch(yourWebAppUrl,options);
       
              }
```

the owner of the script is account A.
the script is also deployed as an executable API file

using Postman: through account A, I run the script successfully, and when editing the sheets I get a notification

my problem is that by using account B to run the script, I also get 200 and in https://script.google.com/home/triggers I see the trigger created, but when I try to edit the sheet, I don't get notifications, just in https://script.google.com/home/triggers there is not even information that the event received an error...

[image]

execution tab: there are no executions

**Updated**
I added the output from the log `Logger.log("ok");`

user B has trigger execution still without information (see screenshot above)

here is a screenshot of the executions for user A

[image]

Comment: About `but when I try to edit the sheet, I don't get notifications, just in https://script.google.com/home/triggers there is not even information that the event received an error`, in this case, when the user of "account B" checks the log, what result will you obtain?

Comment: thank you for your attention to my question
I updated the question added a screenshot

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the sample image. If the sample image is the log of "account B", it seems that no error occurs. So, although I'm not sure about your API, if the API returns some values, how about checking the response value from `UrlFetchApp.fetch`? Or, how about checking the log by putting `console.log("ok")` to the bottom of the function? If you can see the log, it indicates that the script works correctly.

Comment: If you manually create the trigger do you see the samer behaviour?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou if you mean go to user B's account and create a trigger in spreadsheets using extensions, then yes, it works, but I need the script to be accessible from user A

Comment: @Tanaike I updated the question
I already doubt that this is even possible 
I can clearly see that the trigger has been created but I don't understand why it doesn't fire when editing for user B. I have also made both spreadsheets editable

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `need the script to be accessible from user A` - you can't create a trigger on an account that isn't yours?

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. About `user B has trigger execution still without information (see screenshot above)`, even when user B edits the cell, the trigger is not executed. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, for example, when you create a new Spreadsheet and put your script to the created new Spreadsheet and test it again, what result will you obtain? By the way, how do you install the OnEdit trigger?

Comment: @Tanaike yes, I am editing a cell in the spreadsheets file of user B and I am not getting information about the execution. if I create a table under user B and create a trigger through the extensions tab, the trigger works successfully and I see a message in the logs "ok " and also get a message to my endpoint

Comment: @Tanaike I use postman: I run a script with the body "function": "createspreadsheetonedittrigger",
"parameters": [
"xxxx"
]}
and the access token of user A or B

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your reply to my comment.

Comment: at the same time, if user A creates a trigger for user B table, then this will work